# Symfony - Call to a member function setFunction() on null

Tags: php, function, symfony, error-handling, null

I wrote a code to return data but I keep getting an error "Call to a member function setFunction() on null"...

My Service..

```
public function enableNotification($user)
{
    $user->setNotification(1);

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

My Controller..

```
   public function enableNotificationAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $this->container->get('my.route')->enableNotification($user);

    return $this->success('', 'true');
}
```

Comment: In your code there is no place where you call `setFunction()`, please provide code where this error is happening.

Comment: I am sorry setFunction is actually enableNotification..

Comment: Consider updating your question with the actual error message.  If it is enableNotification then my.route does not exist which should have triggered a different error.  If it is setNotification then it means $user is null which in turn implies you are not logged in.  In any event, having the actual error message could reduce a fair amount of speculation.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to a Java NullPointerException. I guess that you have a class with a setFunction() method and your instance of this class is equal to null.

The error message is saying you can't do this:

```
null->setFunction($varToSet);
```

Try to give the code where this occurs

Edit: Regarding your last comment on the question, this means that your service is equal to null. Which version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I defined it in my Entity     /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="system_notifications", type="smallint", options={"default" : 0})
     * @Groups({"user_data"})
     */
    private $notification = false;

Comment: Do you mean that setFunction is in fact setNotification?  If it is the case, your user that you get from $this->getUser() in your controller is null. Are you sure that you have a login user when you call your controller action?

Comment: Yes, that is the case! I am logged in, all other fuctions work just fine.. I am using Postman to check for data return.

Comment: Then you could check your user value before the call of your service with: dump($this->getUser());die;
You could see if it's a User entity instance with that or if it's null.
If you are using Postman to make your call, you have to login your user with Postman too

Comment: I tried that too, but I did't get any luck. If I find the solution, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->container->get('my.route')` returns **null**.
Your service is not instanciated so maybe it is not properly declared or you have a typo in the key of your service.